# html5-canvas move the object on given points

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to move a object on a slanting line. I have given my code. In my code in my 3rd div as I move the slider I am drawing a slanting line on this line I want to move an object. Similar thing I am doing in my 1st div. Where I am moving an object on curve. I am looking for some function in which I will provide the points and the object will follow the points. Here is my code. This code works only in chrome as I am trying to make this only for safari and chrome browsers.

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
            <head>

    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 1000px;
        }
        .canHdr {
            float: left;
            width: 450px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <!-- wrapper -->
        <div class="wrapper">

            <!-- canHdr -->
            <div id="canHdr" class="canHdr" >

                <p>
                    This is my 1st div with bezier curve the curve is getting drawn as slider moves and also a ball in moving on that . 
                </p>

                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                        [No canvas support]
                    </canvas>

                </div>

                <div id="slider1" class="newBg">
                    <input id="slide1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="counterSlider('slide1');" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--/ canHdr -->
            <!-- canHdr2 -->
            <div id="canHdr2" class="canHdr" >

                <p>
                    This is my 2nd div
                </p>

                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                        [No canvas support]
                    </canvas>

                </div>

                <div id="slider2" class="newBg">
                    <input id="slide2" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="counterSlider('slide2');" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- canHdr2 -->
            <!-- canHdr3 -->
            <div id="canHdr3" class="canHdr" >
                <p>
                    This is my 3rd div with slanting line. I want to move a ball on this line when I move the slider. So as the line increases ball will also move on the line.
                </p>

                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                    <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                        [No canvas support]
                    </canvas>

                </div>

                <div id="slider3" class="newBg">
                    <input id="slide3" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange=" drawSlopeCurve2('slide3','100'); " />
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--/ canHdr3 -->
            <!-- canHdr4 -->
            <div id="canHdr4" class="canHdr" >

                <p>
                    This is my 4th div with slanting line. I want to move a ball on this line when I move the slider. So as the line increases ball will also move on the line.
                </p>

                <div class="canOuterHdr" >
                    <canvas id="myCanvas4" width="300" height="195" style="position: relative;">
                        [No canvas support]
                    </canvas>

                </div>

                <div id="slider4" class="newBg">
                    <input id="slide4" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange=" drawSlopeCurve1('slide4','100'); " />
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--/ canHdr4 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /wrapper -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function counterSlider(sID) {

                var slideVal = document.getElementById(sID).value;
                /*if (maxValue ==100){

                 slideVal=slideVal/100;
                 }*/
                slideVal = slideVal / 100;
                var position = slideVal;

                var startPt = {
                    x : 18.8,
                    y : 45
                };
                var controlPt = {
                    x : 28,
                    y : 160
                };
                var endPt = {
                    x : 228,
                    y : 165
                };
                var startPt2 = {
                    x : 20,
                    y : 75
                };
                var controlPt2 = {
                    x : 28,
                    y : 160
                };
                var endPt2 = {
                    x : 228,
                    y : 165
                };

                if (slideVal == 0) {

                    erase('myCanvas2');
                    erase('myCanvas3');
                    erase('myCanvas4');
                    //newSprite('myCanvas1b', 18.8, 45);

                    drawBezier2('myCanvas1', new Array({
                        x : 18.8,
                        y : 45
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);
                    drawBezier2('myCanvas2', new Array({
                        x : 20,
                        y : 75
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);

                } else if (slideVal > 0 && slideVal <= 34) {

                    erase('myCanvas1');
                    //erase('myCanvas1b');
                    erase('myCanvas2');
                    erase('myCanvas3');
                    erase('myCanvas4');

                    drawBezier2('myCanvas1', new Array({
                        x : 18.8,
                        y : 45
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);
                    drawBezier2('myCanvas2', new Array({
                        x : 20,
                        y : 75
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);

                    drawNextPoint('myCanvas1', startPt, controlPt, endPt, position);
                    drawNextPoint('myCanvas2', startPt2, controlPt2, endPt2, position);

                } else if (slideVal > 34 && slideVal <= 67) {

                    erase('myCanvas1');

                    erase('myCanvas2');
                    erase('myCanvas3');
                    erase('myCanvas4');

                    drawBezier2('myCanvas1', new Array({
                        x : 18.8,
                        y : 45
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);
                    drawBezier2('myCanvas2', new Array({
                        x : 20,
                        y : 75
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);

                    drawNextPoint('myCanvas1', startPt, controlPt, endPt, position);
                    drawNextPoint('myCanvas2', startPt2, controlPt2, endPt2, position);

                } else if (slideVal > 67 && slideVal <= 100) {

                    erase('myCanvas1');

                    erase('myCanvas2');
                    erase('myCanvas3');
                    erase('myCanvas4');

                    drawBezier2('myCanvas1', new Array({
                        x : 18.8,
                        y : 45
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);
                    drawBezier2('myCanvas2', new Array({
                        x : 20,
                        y : 75
                    }, {
                        x : 28,
                        y : 160
                    }, {
                        x : 228,
                        y : 165
                    }), slideVal);

                    drawNextPoint('myCanvas1', startPt, controlPt, endPt, position);
                    drawNextPoint('myCanvas2', startPt2, controlPt2, endPt2, position);

                }
            }

            function erase(canvasId) {

                var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.beginPath();
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                canvas.width = canvas.width;

            }


            /**********for backgroundImage********************/

            function _getQBezierValue(t, p1, p2, p3) {
                var iT = 1 - t;
                return iT * iT * p1 + 2 * iT * t * p2 + t * t * p3;

            }

            function getQuadraticCurvePoint(startX, startY, cpX, cpY, endX, endY, position) {
                return {
                    x : _getQBezierValue(position, startX, cpX, endX),
                    y : _getQBezierValue(position, startY, cpY, endY)
                };
            }

            function drawNextPoint(canId, startPt, controlPt, endPt, position) {
                var pt = getQuadraticCurvePoint(startPt.x, startPt.y, controlPt.x, controlPt.y, endPt.x, endPt.y, position);
                position = (position + 0.006) % 1.0;
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0077c1";
                ctx.arc(pt.x, pt.y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }

            function newSprite(canId, mvx, mvy) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0077c1";
                ctx.arc(mvx, mvy, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }

            function drawBezier2(canId, points, slideVal) {

                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);

                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                //context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                //context.strokeStyle = "rgb(113, 113, 213)";
                context.strokeStyle = "#000";
                context.lineWidth = 0.6;
                context.beginPath();
                // Label end points
                //context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                // Draw spline segemnts
                context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
                for (var t = 0; t <= slideVal; t += 0.1) {
                    context.lineTo(Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[0].x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * points[1].x + Math.pow(t, 2) * points[2].x, Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * points[0].y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * points[1].y + Math.pow(t, 2) * points[2].y);
                }

                // Stroke path
                context.stroke();
            }

            function drawSlopeCurve1(sID, maxValue) {
                // erase('canvasTwo');

                var canId = 'myCanvas4';
                var slideVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(sID).value);
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                //line end points
                x1 = 16;
                y1 = 170;
                x2 = 200;
                y2 = 80;

                //get slope (rise over run)
                var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
                //get y-intercept
                var b = y1 - (m * x1);
                //get distance between the two points
                var distance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
                //get new x and y values
                var x = x1 + parseInt(distance / maxValue * slideVal);
                var y = parseInt(m * x + b);

                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(x1, y1);
                context.lineTo(x, y);
                context.lineWidth = 0.6;
                context.stroke();
            }

            function drawSlopeCurve2(sID, maxValue) {
                // erase('canvasTwo');

                var canId = 'myCanvas3';
                var slideVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(sID).value);
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canId);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                //line end points
                x1 = 16;
                y1 = 170;
                x2 = 160;
                y2 = 72;

                //get slope (rise over run)
                var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
                //get y-intercept
                var b = y1 - (m * x1);
                //get distance between the two points
                var distance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
                //get new x and y values
                var x = x1 + parseInt(distance / maxValue * slideVal);
                var y = parseInt(m * x + b);

                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(x1, y1);
                context.lineTo(x, y);
                context.lineWidth = 0.6;
                context.stroke();
            }

        </script>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in Advance. my jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/g7hWD/1/

Comment: Try to edit your source code to only show the essential. You can put a complete example as a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks in Advance. my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/g7hWD/1/

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812923/html5-canvas-move-object-on-line/16818671#16818671